# Hadoop DNS Resolution

Tags: hadoop, dns, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, hosts

I am trying to install a local cluster on a VM. When I have Cloudera Manager open, sometimes the host health check shows as failed and the error message basically says "DNS resolution failed." Sometimes HDFS service shows as failed.  I just would like some ideas on other avenues to troubleshoot. I'm fairly certain it's something simple with the hosts file or some thing with DNS. My OS is Ubuntu.

So far I have edited /etc/hosts to have the exact ipv4 address I got  from running ifconfig

```
10.2.0.15  michael-VirtualBox
```

I deleted the entry

`127.0.0.1   localhost`

I also restarted the networking service.  I executed the command

`"python -c "import socket; print socket.getfqdn(); print socket.gethostbyname(socket.getfqdn())""`

I got back

`127.0.0.1
localhost`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

hadoop heavily relies on being able to perform a forward and reverse lookup of the hostname:

- Resolve a hostname to an IP (forward lookup - DNS A record)
- Resolve an IP to a hostname (reverse lookup - DNS PTR record)

For a local install I'd suggest using `/etc/hosts` because the entries in that file provides forward and reverse lookups for each entry. ALL the nodes in the cluster MUST be able to resolve the hostnames of ALL other servers in the cluster, therefore your `/etc/hosts` file on each server must contain all IP -> Hostname entries for every Vbox VM in your cluster.

The hostname that hadoop sees is the output of `hostname --fqdn` on the server.  Therefore, your `/etc/hosts` file should include both the output of `hostname` and `hostname --fqdn` e.g.

```
127.0.0.1  localhost
10.2.0.15  server1 server1.example.com 
10.2.0.16  server2 server2.example.com 
10.2.0.17  server3 server3.example.com 
10.2.0.18  server4 server4.example.com
```

I am assuming you are using the `host-only` network configuration for each node and all nodes can reach each other.

If you are using cloudera, be sure to restart the `cloudera-scm-agent` after you make the change to `/etc/hosts`

Comment: Ok I will check this out!  Thanks a lot